# How to prove there are only finitely many distinct groups with exactly n elements?

Tags: group-theory

How to prove there are only finitely many distinct groups with exactly n elements, If isomorphic groups are regarded as being the same?

I set $f: a_{ij}\to b_{ij}$, then it is easily to prove $f$ is a homomorphism, but I can't prove f is a bijection.
What I need to do next? I suppose all the groups with exactly n elements are all same

Comment: there are finitely many tables describing the group operation. The cyclic group of order 4 is not isomorphic to the product of two cyclic groups each of order 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is a set containing $n$ elements. Since there are only $n^{n^2}$ possible functions $\ast :G\times G \to G$ (the multiplication function) it follows that $n^{n^2}$ is an upper bound for the number of groups of cardinality $n$ not isomorphic to each other.

Also, $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ (with operation $+$) are two groups of cardinality $4$ not isomorphic to each other. To prove that, it is sufficient to note that for every $ g \in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ we have $2g=0$, while there are elements of order $4$ in $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ .